# Dismiss ModalViewController with NavigationController in iPad When tap outside the view

Tags: ios, ipad, modalviewcontroller

So I am usually follow this way to dismiss ModalViewController when tap outside its view

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if(UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad == UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM())
    {
        if(![self.view.window.gestureRecognizers containsObject:recognizer])
        {
            recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapBehind:)];

            [recognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
            recognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO; //So the user can still interact with controls in the modal view
            [self.view.window addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
            [recognizer release];
        }
    }
}

- (void)handleTapBehind:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:nil]; //Passing nil gives us coordinates in the window

        //Then we convert the tap's location into the local view's coordinate system, and test to see if it's in or outside. If outside, dismiss the view.

        if (![self.view pointInside:[self.view convertPoint:location fromView:self.view.window] withEvent:nil]) 
        {
            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            [self.view.window removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
        }
    }
}
```

its working good with *regular* ModalViewController .. but now I have a modelViewController which is a NavigationViewController with "x" viewController as the root one .. when I use this way and tap on the navigationBar the controller is dismissed , or when I navigate to "y" controller from x controller and want to get back , also when I click the back button the ModalView is dismissed ! which is wrong behavior to me .. I just want the controller to be dismissed in case the tap was completely outside the controller (view area + navigationBar area) .. any one can provide a help please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your code following:

```
- (void)handleTapBehind:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        CGPoint flocation = [sender locationInView:nil]; //Passing nil gives us coordinates in the window

        //Then we convert the tap's location into the local view's coordinate system, and test to see if it's in or outside. If outside, dismiss the view.

        CGPoint tap = [self.view convertPoint:flocation fromView:self.view.window];
        CGPoint tapBar = [self.navigationController.navigationBar convertPoint:flocation fromView:self.view.window];
        if (![self.view pointInside:tap withEvent:nil] && ![self.navigationController.navigationBar pointInside:tapBar withEvent:nil])
        {
            // Remove the recognizer first so it's view.window is valid.
            [self.view.window removeGestureRecognizer:sender];
            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Remove UITapGestureRecognizer from window when tap on UIBarButtonItem

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.view.window removeGestureRecognizer:self.tapOutsideGestureRecognizer];
}
```